# GitLab CI - How can run only one manual job, and disable the others after it has ran?

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci

I have multiple manual jobs, where only one needs to be selected. Once one is selected I want to disable the other jobs. In this example I have 3 npm jobs, once the dev chooses one of these, I want to disable the other two jobs from being able to run. I was going to add a needs dependency but that only allows you to select a job that has already run.

Here is what I have so far:

```
publish_patch:
  stage: deploy
  image: node:latest
  before_script:
    - cp $SCRT_NPMRC_TOKEN .npmrc
  script:
    - npm version patch
    - npm publish
    - git checkout main
    - git add package.json package-lock.json
    - git commit -m "automatic version commit" 
    - git push -o ci.skip
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  when: manual

publish_minor:
  stage: deploy
  image: node:latest
  before_script:
    - cp $SCRT_NPMRC_TOKEN .npmrc
  script:
    - npm version minor
    - npm publish
    - git checkout main
    - git add package.json package-lock.json
    - git commit -m "automatic version commit" 
    - git push -o ci.skip
  when: manual


publish_major:
  stage: deploy
  image: node:latest
  before_script:
    - cp $SCRT_NPMRC_TOKEN .npmrc
  script:
    - npm version patch
    - npm publish
    - git checkout main
    - git add package.json package-lock.json
    - git commit -m "automatic version commit" 
    - git push -o ci.skip
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  when: manual
```

Comment: I don't think this is directly possible. Once a pipeline is created, you can't disable/exclude jobs from that pipeline. Within your script, you can probably introspect the pipeline using the API to determine if one of the other jobs has run (and prevent the push). However, this won't stop the jobs from being run and won't change how they appear in the UI.